# Spring JMS MappingJackson2MessageConverter - No way to handle errors

Tags: java, json, jackson, spring-jms

I am using Spring JMS, and I am using the `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` to pass along messages between various components.

My core problem is that when the `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` experiences an internal deserialization error, when deserializing a String into some Object, these exceptions are not raised in any way that I can respond to them. My Error Handler logic never gets called, and no exceptions are thrown that I have access to. These deserialization errors appear to be completely swallowed and, while they are logged in the console, I am offered no chance to perform custom logic in response to them.

I define my `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` bean as follows:

```
  @Bean
  public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
  }
```

I define a JMS Listener factory as follows:

```
  @Bean
  public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerQueueFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
      DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, JmsErrorHandler jmsErrorHandler) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setErrorHandler(jmsErrorHandler); // <-- I expect this to be used
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);

    return factory;
  }
```

Of importance in the above line is the `setErrorHandler` call. I have defined a simple `ErrorHandler` object that is attempting to catch errors that my `@JmsListener` methods may throw. This simple error handler looks like this:

```
  public class JmsErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  @Override
  public void handleError(Throwable t) {
    System.out.println("WE HAVE THE ERROR!");
  }
}
```

My listener is also simple, as follows:

```
  @JmsListener(id = MY_ID, destination = MY_DEST)
  public void processMessage(MyPojoMessage myPojoMessage) {
     // This code is obviously never reached, since the serialization error occurs.
```

Overall, this is a very simple and basic setup. Now when I send an invalid message, that Jackson will *fail* to parse, I get the following errors in my console:

```
19-10-2020 09:05:33.933 [35m[DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1][0;39m [31mWARN [0;39m o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.

org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.example.processMessage(com.example.MyPojoMessage)' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Failed to convert JSON message content; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException
```

This exception is expected - since I provide an invalid payload that Jackson cannot serialize. However, there is seemingly *no way* for me to configure the code to actually catch this exception in a way I can respond to it. I am setting the Error Handler in the above code. Yet the logs complain that `no ErrorHandler has been set` which seems wrong.

I see no other ways to get a reference to this Jackson inner exception. Is there any way?

Comment: I don't see how it can use your jmsListenerQueueFactory method because you have given it your own method  signature. So that method is likely not getting called, so the error handler is not set.

Comment: If you are referring to the method parameters of the factory, these are beans injected by type via Spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like ConditionalOnMissingBean autoconfiguration is on [bean name](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.java#L76)

So you should have something like this.

```
@Bean
  public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
      DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, JmsErrorHandler jmsErrorHandler) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setErrorHandler(jmsErrorHandler); // <-- I expect this to be used
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
  }
```

Comment: So this was exactly it. So I admit I simplified my code a little bit. My bean was actually annotated with a name: `@Bean(name = "queue-listener-factory")` HOWEVER! In my `@JmsListener` I was *not* referencing this Bean name. 


I added `containerFactory = "queue-listener-factory"` to my `@JmsListener` annotation and now everything works as expected!

Comment: Also, for anyone reading in the future: this answer is the exact solution to the question as literally asked.